# Sort strings of mixed types and different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['286a2', '17', '286a1', '373', '200b', '150'], 'B': range(6)})

       A  B
0  286a2  0
1     17  1
2  286a1  2
3    373  3
4   200b  4
5    150  5
```

which I want to sort according to `A`. When I do this using

```
df.sort_values(by='A')
```

I obtain

```
       A  B
5    150  5
1     17  1
4   200b  4
2  286a1  2
0  286a2  0
3    373  3
```

which is almost correct: I would like to have `17` before `150` but don't know how to do this as those entries are not just values but actual strings consisting of numerical values and letters. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

About the pattern of the entries:

It is always a numeric value first of arbitrary length, then it can be followed by characters, which can be followed by numerical values again.

Comment: hmm.. it does not seem that `df.sort_values` accepts function definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) characters to `.` with cast to `float` with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.index = df['A'].str.replace('[a-zA-Z]+','.').astype(float)
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       A  B
0     17  1
1    150  5
2   200b  4
3  286a1  2
4  286a2  0
5    373  3
```

Comment: isn't `"286a2"` one position higher that it should be? You can try extracting **all** digits from the string first.

Comment: That fails for the `286a1` and `286a2` entry, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant to jezrael's

```
In [1706]: df.assign(
              A_=df.A.str.replace('[/\D]', '.').astype(float)   # or '[a-zA-Z]+'
              ).sort_values(by='A_').drop('A_', 1)
Out[1706]:
       A  B
1     17  1
5    150  5
4   200b  4
2  286a1  2
0  286a2  0
3    373  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try , `natsort`

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
df.set_index('A').reindex(natsorted(df.A, key=lambda y: y.lower())).reset_index()
Out[395]: 
       A  B
0     17  1
1    150  5
2   200b  4
3  286a1  2
4  286a2  0
5    373  3
```

Comment: @Cleb Yw, nice day ~ :)!